# Extracting a string/numbers from a file name

Tags: r

I have to extract a specific date from a bunch of filenames. I have found that following code can help with it:

```
dates <- unique(gsub(pattern = "xxxxxx", replacement = "xxxx", x = filenames))
```

**Example file name:** `LC08_L1TP_211048_20180705_20180717_01_T1_2018-07-05_B5.TIF`

**Date to extract:** `20180705`

Can anyone please tell me what to fill in for **pattern** and **replacement** in the above code.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Do you want to replace the pattern or just simply check whether the string contains the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the 4th underscore-separated field try these.  They also work if x is a vector.

**1)** This uses read.table.

```
x <- "LC08_L1TP_211048_20180705_20180717_01_T1_2018-07-05_B5.TIF"

read.table(text = x, sep = "_")[[4]]
## [1] 20180705
```

**2)** or using `sub` and a regular expression use this which also works with vector x:

```
sub("^([[:alnum:]]+_){3}(\\d+)_.*", "\\2", x)
## [1] "20180705"
```

**3)** If the date always appears in character positions 18 through 25 then:

```
substring(x, 18, 25)
## [1] "20180705"
```

**4)** If instead of the above assumption, the assumption is that we want the first occurrence of 8 digits following an underscore then:

```
sub("^.*?_(\\d{8}).*", "\\1", x)
## [1] "20180705"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the underscores are in the same place, then this will be enough:

```
unlist(strsplit(str, "_"))[4]
```